# Echo something with PHP code in the xml file

Tags: php, xml, output, echo

I am a novice and I work in PHP. And I do not know anything about xml. My English is not very good. If you see a typo, please edit it

Please see the code below

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$array = ["a", "b", "c"];
echo $array[0];
```

There is a problem with the output and I can not use the echo. The photo below is my output

[image: view photo]

please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out from the url that you want to create a sitemap. You should see the output inside a `xml` code. for example:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$array = ["a", "b", "c"];

echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"."\n";
echo "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'>"."\n";
 echo "<url>";
 echo "<loc>".$array[0]."</loc>";
 echo "<lastmod>".$array[1]."</lastmod>";
 echo "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
 echo "</url>";
echo "</urlset>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging, then comment out the `header` line. Once the content type header is set, output in that content type only. The browser is expecting a well formed xml. So just printing that out won't work.